# Is there any better way to repeatedly call function for each case statement

Tags: bash, function

I wrote a bash script to automate lamp installing in my server, they work great but there's a problem regarding its readability.

```sh
  # Asking if want to install PHP or build from source
  read -p "This script will install PHP, do you want to install it (y/n)?" phpchoice
  case "$phpchoice" in
    [Yy]* ) isinstallphp=yes;;
    [Nn]* ) isinstallphp=no;;
    * ) echo "invalid";;
  esac

  if [ isinstallphp == "yes" ]; then
    # Prompt for php version
    options=("php5.6" "php7.0" "php7.1" "php7.2" "php7.3" "php7.4" "php8.0" "php8.1")
    function do_something () {
      echo -e "${Ye}You picked ${Wh}$php_opt${Ye}, will be installing that instead${Nc}"
    }
    select php_opt in "${options[@]}"; do
      case "$php_opt,$REPLY" in
        php5.6,*|*,php5.6) do_something; break ;;
        php7.0,*|*,php7.0) do_something; break ;;
        php7.1,*|*,php7.1) do_something; break ;;
        php7.2,*|*,php7.2) do_something; break ;;
        php7.3,*|*,php7.3) do_something; break ;;
        php7.4,*|*,php7.4) do_something; break ;;
        php8.0,*|*,php8.0) do_something; break ;;
        php8.1,*|*,php8.1) do_something; break ;;
      esac
    done    
  fi
```

The case statement part where I put `do_something` function looks messy, all the function do is echo which php option user choose in color. Is there any way to shorten the code ?

Comment: Is `do_something` always the same?

Comment: Well yeah, they echo same variable (`php_opt`) which is retrieved from case result.

Comment: Tip: include delimiter on both sides, then you can get away with one `case` case, `case ",$php_opt,$REPLY," in *,php5.6,*) do_something; break ;;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The case statement part where I put `do_something` function looks messy, all the function do is echo which php option user choose in color. Is there any way to shorten the code ?

It appears that you are accommodating the dual possibilities that the user chooses an option by typing its number or by typing the item text.  One simplification would be to require the user to make their selection by item number only, in which case you would only need to confirm that `$php_opt` was not set to NULL.  The `case` statement would not be required at all.

If you want to retain the full input functionality of the current script, then you can still do better than the current code.  Instead of a long `case` statement covering all the options, check whether `$php_opt` is NULL, and if it is, check whether `$REPLY` is equal to one of the options.  There is a variety of ways you could implement that, but I like this one:

```
validate_option() {
  local choice=$1
  while [[ $# -gt 1 ]]; do
    shift
    [[ "$choice" = "$1" ]] && return 0
  done
  return 1
}

# ...

    select php_opt in "${options[@]}"; do
      if [[ -n "$php_opt" ]] || validate_option "$REPLY" "${options[@]}"; then
        do_something
      fi
    done
```

I find that a lot clearer.  Note also that the `validate_option` function is reusable, and that this approach is completely driven by the option list, so you don't need to modify this code if the option list changes.

**Addendum**

You additionally raised a question about your given `do_something` function not printing the selected option when the user enters the option value instead of its number.  This will have been a behavior of your original code, too.  It arises from the fact that the `select` command sets the specified variable (`php_opt` in your case) to NULL in the event that the user enters a non-empty response that is not one of the menu item numbers.

If you want to avoid that, and perhaps also to have the selected value in the form of the option string for other, later processing, then you probably want to address that issue in the body of the `select` statement.  Something like this variation might do, for example:

```
    select php_opt in "${options[@]}"; do
      if [[ -n "$php_opt" ]] ||
          { php_opt=$REPLY; validate_option "$php_opt" "${options[@]}"; }; then
        do_something
      fi
    done
```

That copies the user-entered text into `$php_opt` in the event that the user entered something other than an option number.  Do note that that behavior change might have other effects later in the script, too.

Comment: This works, but when I type e.g. php7.2 explicitly into select prompt, it fails to output it. Is this how select are implemented ? Only deals with index number and not text?

Comment: @Liso, that is a behavior that your original code will have exhibited, too.  I have written an addendum to this answer to discuss it.

Comment: Sweet ! You are a lifesaver ! I intended to fix that behavior but I don't know where to start, thank you so much !

Answer (score 1):

What you're checking is if $php_opt or $REPLY is in the $options array:

```sh
array_contains() {
  local -n ary=$1
  local elem=$2
  local IFS=$'\034'
  [[ "${IFS}${ary[*]}$IFS" == *"${IFS}${elem}$IFS"* ]]
}

#...
    select php_opt in "${options[@]}"; do
      if array_contains options "$php_opt" || array_contains options "$REPLY"; then
        do_something
        break
      fi
    done
```

`local -n` requires bash v4.3+

Octal 034 is the ASCII "FS" character, it's *unlikely* to be in your data

Comment: I'll try this in my lxd container, will follow up after. Thanks !

Comment: Or store the options as Associative array keys.

Comment: This works, but when I type e.g. `php7.2` explicitly into select prompt, it fails to output it. Is this how select are implemented ? Only deals with index number and not text?

Comment: I'm not seeing the same thing. Is it possible you added a space or tab? Add `declare -p php_opt REPLY` before the if statement.

Answer (score 1):

`select` sets the given variable name to the selected string, *only* if a valid selection is made. If an invalid selection is made (ie. not one of the available numbers), `$php_opt` will be empty. Even if a valid selection was made in a previous iteration, it will be reset to empty.

Hence you just need to test if `$php_opt` is empty or not:

```
select php_opt in "${options[@]}"; do
    # check for literal reply
    reply=${REPLY,,}
    for i in "${options[@]}"; do
        if [[ "$i" == "$reply" ]]; then
            php_opt=$reply
            break
        fi
    done

    if [[ "$php_opt" ]]; then
        do_something
        break
    else
        echo "$REPLY: invalid selection"
    fi
done
```

Or with `case`:

```
select php_opt in "${options[@]}"; do
    # check for literal reply
    reply=${REPLY,,}
    for i in "${options[@]}"; do
        if [[ "$i" == "$reply" ]]; then
            php_opt=$reply
            break
        fi
    done

    case $php_opt in
        '') echo "$REPLY: invalid selection";;
         *) do_something; break
    esac
done
```

From `help select`:

> If the line consists of the number corresponding to one of the displayed words, then NAME is set to that word. If the line is empty, WORDS and the prompt are redisplayed.  If EOF is read, the command completes.  Any other value read causes NAME to be set to null. The line read is saved in the variable REPLY.

Also note that you are missing `$` in your if statement.

**edit:** as per the comment, I added a check for a literal name, as well as a number. It's case insensitive, `PHP7.0` is valid input. Using the original array is easier to maintain, than a second list of patterns in a case statement.

To make things tidier, you can also put `do_something` *after* `select` (so you only need `break`). Maybe something like `[[ "$reply" == [Qq] ]] && exit` too. Similarly in your very first case statement, just do `exit` if the reply is no.

Comment: You don't seem to have appreciated the full effect of the `case` statement in the OP's original code.  It provides for the user to enter a selection not only by typing its number, but also by typing its text.  The alternatives you present do not afford the same flexibility.

Comment: @JohnBollinger That may be the case. It's not especially clear from the code. This function can be added with a smaller case statement.

Comment: Well, @dan, I don't see any other reason why `$REPLY` would be involved in the original `case` statement.  It did take me a minute to figure that out, but it seems pretty clear in retrospect.  In any event, the OP has posed followup questions on the two other answers that seem to confirm my interpretation.